# Github pages reference file from project repo

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm trying to create Github project pages which use the actual repo's contents.

```
main project:  github.com/me/project
               github.com/me/project/css.css
               ...
project pages: github.com/me/project/docs/
               github.com/me/project/docs/index.html
```

I assumed the *point* of keeping pages in `docs/` is being able to reference the files in the actual repo.

Is this even possible? How would I use `github.com/me/project/css.css` from `github.com/me/project/docs/index.html`?

Edit: I am aware of [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/), but I'd like a native Github solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an incredibly simple solution when using the `gh-pages` branch:

Say we have an image `"img.png"` in `assets` branch root directory, we can use it from another branch like so

```
<img src="../assets/img.png">
```

---

Update *September 2018*: Does not work any longer.